# Problems with personally constructed complex number class

Tags: c++, class, complex-numbers

I am having trouble figuring out why my complex number class isn't adding correctly or working exactly how I want it to. When I add two complex numbers together I get something really weird that isn't supposed to be. I keep trying to figure out what's wrong, but can't quite figure it out. I need to keep the structure because I am going to use it for another purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber{
private:
    double real, imag;
public:
    ComplexNumber(double i,double j){
    real = i;
    imag = j;}

    ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber c){
    real += c.real;
    imag += c.imag;
    }

    ComplexNumber squared(){
    real = (pow(real,2) - pow(imag,2));
    imag = 2*real*imag;
    }

    double abs() {
    return sqrt(real*real + imag*imag);
    }
    void print(){
        char sign = (imag<0) ? '-' : '+';
        cout<<real<<" "<<sign<<" "<<(imag>0 ? imag : -imag)<<'i'<<endl;
    }

};

int main() {
ComplexNumber c1(3,4), c2(1,1);
ComplexNumber c3=c1.add(c2);
c3.print();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `add` member function promises to return a `ComplexNumber` but it doesn't. You then attempt to use the return value, invoking *undefined behaviour*. `squared` is similarly broken.

You need to figure out whether you want `add` to implement the behaviour of operator `+=` or `+`. In the first case, you'd need to return a reference to the object being modified:

```
ComplexNumber& add(ComplexNumber c)
{//          ^
  real += c.real;
  imag += c.imag;
  return *this;
}
```

In the second case, do not modify the object but create a new one and return it:

```
ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber c)
{
  return Complex(real + c.real, imag + c.imag);
}
```

Note that in this case it may make sense to use a non-member function instead.

I suggest looking at [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) for an example of a good implementation.

Comment: @apples123 I added some explanations and code samples. Also, I reverted your edit because you had removed all the code.

Answer (score 0):

As declared, your Add function should end with:
return ComplexNumber(real,imag);

But that makes me wonder -- it does not sound like "add into", it sounds like it would be "add args and this number and return a new Complex."  You can clarify your interface a bit. If "Add" means "Add into" then it might be void and return nothing. Or it might return itself, so you can do more with it after adding into it. (That's what "+=" does.) If that is what you are looking for, you would return ComplexNumber& (a reference to ComplexNumber) and end with: 
return *this;

In any case, why did you compiler not warn you when a function did not return with a value? Did you set the warning level to "never warn me"? Turn your compiler warnings up. Not returning a value when the function is declared to have a result is a basic error, it shouldn't even be just a warning.

Comment: So the other problem with your add function is that it modified C1. To work in this example, don't modify the members of this, but simply:
`return ComplexNumber(real + c.real, imag+c.imag);`